# String input in C

Tags: c, string, c-strings

At the same time sequentially whenever I take input string and a character by using built in function `gets` and `scanf` fucntion I am facing a problem.

At first whenever I take input string by using `gets` and then I take input a character by the help of `scanf` function then the compiler doesn't respond to take character though it takes input from the `gets` function and direct skip the `scanf` function to take a character from user.

See the code below and run it to your compiler to understand the problem

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   int main()
   {

  int i,l,T,exit;

  char str[1000];
  char ch;

  scanf("%d",&T);

  while( (T-- ) ){


       gets(str);

       scanf("%c",&ch);

       l = strlen(str);

       exit = 0;

       for( i = 0; i < l; i++ ){

            if( str[i] == ch )
                      exit++;
        }

       if(!(exit))
          printf("'\%c\' is not present\n",ch);

     else
         printf("Occurrence of '\%c\' in '\%s\' = %d\n",ch,exit);

    }

    return 0;

     }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8MtamnaUCcOxIGBr). The `scanf()` seems working well.

Comment: It is not working for me. It works if I add for example printf("enter the char"); or fflush(NULL). Looks like the scanf just getting the first char from the stream. And as you indicated gets should be used. The compiler also warns the same. I think better the OP replaces gets with scanf.

Comment: I'd recommend scanning in a string and using the `strchr()` function to check if a character is present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix input methods. Read this discussion for details.

http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html

I suggest replacing the gets with scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Many mistakes found. Try this, it should work fine

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
int main() 
{
    int i, l, T, exit;
    char str[1000];
    char ch;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T>0) {
        T--;
        scanf("%s", str);
        scanf(" %c", &ch);// Remember that there's a space next to %c
        l = strlen(str);
        exit = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (str[i] == ch)
                exit=i+1;
        }
        if (!(exit))
            printf("'\%c\' is not present\n", ch);
        else
            printf("Occurrence of '\%c\' in '%s' = %d\n", ch, str, exit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And please indent your code properly

Comment: `while (T--)` is all that is required, but you should check the return of `scanf` to make sure you really have `T` AND that `(T > 0)`.

Comment: changed! Thanks @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: It still doesn't work Sameera !! and with the code of yours i am still facing the same problem as before.

Comment: what problem are you facing?